# Model attributes visibility inside admin panel

Tags: strapi

Is there a way to manage model attributes visibility inside admin panel per action? Suppose I've generated `Project` API with `name` and `slug` attributes via the CLI. I want to hide `slug` from `new` and `edit` actions and use `beforeCreate` callback to generate it. Can I override the view or there are relative settings?

Answer (score 0):

The logic used to populate admin fields is mainly contained in this file: https://github.com/wistityhq/strapi-generate-admin/blob/master/files/api/admin/public/src/strapi/explorer/explorer.service.js#L25

If you want to add specific behavior for some fields, please add custom code in this file. To do so:

- `cd api/admin/public/src/`
- `npm install` (node 4 required)
- `gulp serve`
- visit http://localhost:3002
- edit the logic here: https://github.com/wistityhq/strapi-generate-admin/blob/master/files/api/admin/public/src/strapi/explorer/explorer.service.js#L25
- finally, run `gulp dist` to save your updates

In a next Strapi version, admin fields display will be probably based on an external JSON file or on an `adminOptions` field located in each attribute of `myModel.settings.json` files.